# reference is not generated after compiling with latexmk -f -pdf

Tags: bibtex, latexmk

I encounter a problem to use `latexmk` to compile my paper.

Story:
I have my paper on overleaf online and the generated pdf view contains everything including the references.

Then I would like to work offline. So I git clone the repository and try to compile the source file with `latexmk -f -pdf`, which is how the overleaf compiles.

However the generated pdf file doesn't include the references. Of course, all the citations in the paper are showing as '?'.

For me, I am using windows and install `latexmk` with MikTex. 
There is only on tex file in my repos and the bib file has the same name with my tex file.
Another information is the generated `.bll` fill is empty.

Any clues on this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Is there any helpful message in the `.log` file? Do you get a `.blg` file (if Biber or BibTeX was run there should be a `.blg` file)?

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) we probably need some code here? did you spell the citation key correctly? Any warnings in the log file?

Comment: try running `latexmk` without the option `-f` ("force continued processing past errors") and look at the error messages

Answer (score 1):

thanks a lot for the quick response! @moewe's answer lead me to resolve the problem.

I have the .blg file generated and it saying "I couldn't open style file IEEEtran.bst" which is not exist on my local. So after I download the file and put it in my repos with the tex source file, it works! The references show up.

The following is the beginning of blg file contents:

> This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2016/Cygwin)
>   Capacity: max_strings=35307, hash_size=35307, hash_prime=30011 The
>   top-level auxiliary file: chang18exploiting.aux I couldn't open style
>   file IEEEtran.bst
>   ---line 489 of file chang18exploiting.aux  : \bibstyle{IEEEtran  :                   } I'm skipping whatever remains of this command I found no style
>   file---while reading file chang18exploiting.aux You've used 43
>   entries,
>               0 wiz_defined-function locations,
>               127 strings with 1157 characters,

@deleif, @DG' , thanks for replying. The log files contains lots of warning like:

> LaTeX Warning: Citation `xxxxxx' on page 4 undefined on input line 359
>   .
>
> LaTeX Warning: Citation `yyyyyy' on page 4 undefined on input line 39
>   1.

Comment: However, I found the IEEETrans.bst file in my MikTex install path under C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\bibtex\bst\ieeetran\ shouldn't it be found during compiling?

Comment: It should be found. But your BibTeX identifies as `TeX Live 2016/Cygwin` while you mention MikTeX. So I assume that you have several TeX distributions installed that interact badly. If you don't have a good reason for several installations, you may want to remove all but one.

Comment: Perfect! I removed the Tex live from cygwin and remove the IEEETrans.bst file. And it still works. Thanks a lot!